# Oracle : commit and rollback, unwanted records committed

Tags: oracle, commit, rollback

I always thought that uncommitted data was rollbacked at the end even though it was not explicitly said but maybe not all the time.

In a putty session, I called a ksh script. In this script, a sqlplus session is opened

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s user/psw
```

Inside the sqlplus session, a procedure is called.

Here is the scheme of the procedure (I sum up)

```
begin
   for product IN    c_product (a cursor)
   loop
       ...
       insert into product values ....;

       calling another procedure (error);

       if error <> 0 then
          raise myException;
       end if;

       -- every 30 insertions
           commit;
   end loop;

   myException block
      dbms_output.put_line(.....);
      problem = true;

   end of programm;
```

Let's say that there is error and the exception is raised. Normally there should be a rollback inside this exception block and there would be no problem : all uncommitted data are rolled back and the procedure gives back the hand to the sqlplus session

But let's say there is no rollback in the exception block.

We go back to the sqlplus session, exit it to the ksh session and we are back in the putty session.

Opening a new sqlplus session and requesting product table, the uncommitted data is there !!

switch off putty, go back, requesting..still there.
restart database, requesting... still there : it is definitely committed but there was no commit : so the system committed the uncommitted data ? why?

-- in the ksh

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s user/psw <<EOF
set exitc off
var error number

execute package.myProcedure(param1, :error)

exit :error

EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, SQL*Plus commits when you exit.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-38F2E554-42E6-4783-8F23-81E6BAE5D62C):

> **12.41.22 SET EXITC[OMMIT] {ON | OFF}**
>
> Specifies whether the default EXIT behavior is COMMIT or ROLLBACK.
>
> The default setting is ON, which means that work is committed on exit, whether you expected it to be committed or not. Set EXITCOMMIT OFF to rollback work on exit.

That option was added in Oracle 11g release 2; before that a plain `exit` always committed.

---

You can also tell SQL*Plus to exit when an exception is raised, and as part of that can tell it to rollback, by doing something like:

```
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
```

at the start of your SQL script ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/WHENEVER-SQLERROR.html#GUID-66C1C12C-5E95-4440-A37B-7CCE7E33491C)).

If nothing was raised then it would then still commit by default on exit. Though explicitly committing or rolling back is cleaner and safer anyway.

But that `whenever sqlerror` handling only applies for unhandled exceptions. In your example pseudocode you seem to be catching exceptions and just printing the message (which assumes you have `serveroutput on`). That would mean the PL/SQL block would be seen as successful, as far as the SQL*Plus client is concerned, so it wouldn't cause it to exit, or roll back.

If you didn't catch the exceptions, or did that and then re-raised the exception or threw your own exception, then the PL/SQL block itself would throw that exception, SQL*Plus would see it, and could exit based on the `whenever sqlerror` setting, rolling back as it does so.

---

You've added code that does:

```
exit :error
```

That changes the behaviour, it seems...

[From the docs again](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/EXIT.html#GUID-81B9B8B3-4236-4AAC-9EE8-75B873009D03), the syntax for the exit command is:

> `{EXIT | QUIT} [SUCCESS | FAILURE | WARNING | n | variable | :BindVariable] [COMMIT | ROLLBACK]`

and

> EXIT with no clauses commits and exits with a value of SUCCESS.

What seems to be happening is that if you just do `exit` then it honours the `exitcommit` setting; but if you supply either of the other clauses then the default for the other is used. So `exit :error` is treated as `exit :error commit`. And as [the `exitcommit` table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-38F2E554-42E6-4783-8F23-81E6BAE5D62C__BABDFJHH) shows, that expanded syntax would mean it would commit.

The `exitcommit` documentation doesn't say that when it says it affects "whether the default EXIT behavior is COMMIT or ROLLBACK" it only means `exit` with no arguments; and the `exit` documentation doesn't refer to `exitcommit` at all so it's not even clear there that applies to plain `exit` with no arguments, never mind that it doesn't with any others.

But from experimentation, that is what it's doing. The `exitcommit` setting was added in Oracle 11gR2, so the behaviour and documentation may not have been updated consistently.

So, you would need to change your exit to:

```
exit :error rollback
```

which seems a bit unintuitive. (And if you aren't already, you need to check you do commit on success after the final few times around the loop - if your cursor query returns 31 rows, you commit after the 30th, then when is the 31st committed?)

Comment: You are right..I dont understand this behaviour. autocommit is off by default but exitc on !!! I dont get it

Comment: @mlwacosmos - they are different things. The autocommit concept is a common connection property (e.g. in JDBC), while `exitcommit` is a specific client setting for SQL\*Plus (and SQLcl). `autocommit` commits after every statement, which I've never seen as a good thing, in SQL\*Plus or anywhere else. It slows things down and means you can't recover from mistakes or treat multiple statements as a single transaction (without wrapping them in a PL/SQL block, anyway). `exitcommit` will only commit once, at the end of the session, which is arguably useful-ish. It's always defaulted to `on`...

Comment: In the ksh, after opening the sqlplus session and before calling the procedure I added a set exitc off. Unfortunatly, it does change anything : the unwanted data are still committed.

Comment: I just tested 'set exitc' and it works as expected. It surely will not remove data from prior sessions.

Comment: @mlwacosmos - not sure what to tell you, it works for me. If you are sure you aren't explicitly committing somewhere, are you issuing any DDL - like creating or dropping objects? DDL always commits. It's a little unclear if you're creating a procedure (and then maybe dropping it at the end) or just calling an existing one...

Comment: just calling..the data are surely not committed by program

Comment: @mlwacosmos - you're also committing in your loop, so the inserts you do before calling the procedure could be committed in a later iteration - depending on how you are really handling the exceptions, which isn't entirely clear in the pseudocode. And are you sure the procedure you call isn't committing? A [mre] might reveal something more concrete.

Comment: In the loop, I commit every 30 records. I checked with log...commit in the loop is not called for all the data between last commit and 29 after. By the way, if I call rollback in the exception block, the unwanted data are erased (so they were not committed at the end of the program)

Comment: Yes... if your real code is doing `exit :error` then that apparently changes how it works. I've added to my answer. Nice to know I can still learn something new about SQL*Plus after using it for nearly 30 years, I suppose...